# Как с интегрировать elasticsearch-php с Logstash и Kibana

Tags: php, elasticsearch

Я установила в своей проект на Laravel elasticsearch-php. Появилась нужна анализе данных посредством Longstash и Kibana, но я не могу понять, как мне интегрировать elasticsearch-php c остальным стеком.

Comment: они никак не интегрируются. из php-клиента вы работаете напрямую с ES, логстэш предназначен для отпраки сообщений в ES (являясь таким образом другим клиентом), кибана помогает с визуализацией содержимого. так что пока что вам видимо просто нужно поставить кибану, натравить на ES и делать из нее нужные запросы.

Comment: @etki, вот, спасибо большое. Именно это меня и интересовало, а то  информации на этот счет очень мало. Получается я работаю с этим стеком также, как если бы я работала без интеграции elasticsearch с Laravel?

Comment: Да, одно запихивает данные, другое читает, в центре ES как хранилище. Напишите лучше отдельным вопросом свою основную задачу, этот стек не очень вяжется непосредственно с анализом данных.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я думаю вам поможет этот туториал http://www.darwinbiler.com/parsing-and-sending-laravel-logs-to-elasticsearch-using-logstash/

Comment: спасибо за ответ, но это немного не то, что мне нужно. Но, в любом случае, спасибо большое за отклик)